# Why can't I see my work in render?

Tags: rendering

Why can't I see my work once rendered? [There was a link to a file on PasteAll.org, but the File is no longer on that site.]

Comment: The error says exactly what you need to do when you try to render the scene. Can't be more obvious.

Comment: @Denis That's true, but the mesh doesn't render even when you fix that problem.

Comment: I would try redoing the material. I don't know what the problem is (I'm not really much of a BI user), but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Denis Im not even getting an error, when i switch to render I just see chips of it.

Comment: What are you truing to do with solidify modifier? the issue is the flipped normals

Comment: Im using it for a real time "anime style" outline that changes when as I edit. Its a big part of it.

Comment: you have mixed materials, the main is blender internal and outline is cycles nodes

Comment: @Steven Don't do that. Try taking a normal node, taking the output of the dot, crunching down on it a lot with a color ramp node until you get an outline, and then mix it. Might not give what you want, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Im honestly not sure witch to be using for this project, I want to make a RWBY style show. When I use cycles I cant see my colors in the viewport I asked about that here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32071/view-colors-outside-of-render

Comment: In cycles, you can view it with the texture viewport mode, the materials viewport mode, and the rendered mode.

Answer (score 2):

First disable nodes from the outline material (Cycles materials can't be rendered in Blender Internal render engine).

Then in outline material enable Transparency and set Fresnel to 5

[image]

Comment: Should probably get rid of specular also.

Comment: Is there a way to make is solid black and less reflective, see around the eyes where the inside is reflected out, im hoping to see solid lines like in the viewport less fancy shading. http://postimg.org/image/xilk4ncff/

Comment: @Steven what is the reason that you need to use that in rendered mode?

Comment: Because I want the end result to be like what I have in the viewport essentially, Im going for an Anime style series. RWBY(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-p4iS_p3b8E) is a good example, id like the end result to be of this nature.

Comment: Then use opengl rendering while in camera view

Answer (score 0):

To render image or movie clip the scene other than Rendered Viewport Shading, set view to active camera, open Render menu on the top of the screen and select OpenGL Render Image or OpenGL Render Animation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I'm already aware of that U had it right with your first answer. Its close but i want the solid black like that I you see in the viewport, i'm not just trying to see the rendered version period. I want to get the same results i'm seeing in the viewport in the final rendered version.

Comment: @Steven Im not sure that will be possible with the setting that you want.

Comment: Gotcha, Is it a "fool's gold' mission to want to have this anime/toon style color, with an outline that changes as the mesh does and have is all be viewable in the viewport as i edit? Im trying not to constantly be rendering. In CR I can get outlines and everything right in the render but no color in the viewport, in BR I can get the look right in the view port but cant get it on the render T_T

Comment: In cycles is wouldnt be possible to edit while in rendered mode, and I'm not sure why you have problem seeing the result in edit mode.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36450 This other one im working on is a good exaple, I can get it all to show up in render but the color wont show up in edit mode.

Comment: @Steven are you talking about vertex color or the outline? I can see the outline ok in edit mode

Comment: yes vertex color