# View Colors outside of render

Tags: 3d-view

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36447

Is there a way to make me see the look of the mesh outside of rendering like in blender render? Id be cool with vertex paint or UV.

Side note: If I want to view most all my effects while editing, Which has more available to view BR or CR?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to realize shading effects from Cycles BSDF node trees in the viewport via OpenGL. You must use the Viewport render mode or do a full render to the frame buffer to realize the shader effects that you've set up.

At this point, you're pretty much limited to image textures, ambient occlusion, DOF, and shadeless mode for viewport view when not in render mode. I suppose you could technically bake your cycles shaders to a texture image, and then apply it to the mesh for viewing in the viewport, but that seems counterproductive.

Comment: Dang, how about with vertex pain, with a color ramp for toon effect? Could i see that?

Comment: I don't think so, you can use Vertex Colour paint as an input into a Cycles nodetree, but you can't route the output of a Cycles shader back to the Vertex Paint map.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh I think the OP just wants to see the vertex colors in the 3D view.

Comment: @gandalf3 In the OP's blend file, you can see that the model has toon shading along with a strong edge effect. I'm not sure there's a way to replicate that with a Vertex Colour map is there?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh The rendered colors originate from vertex colors though. I read the OP's question as asking if the *colors* could be seen in the 3D view without rendering, not necessarily if the *shading* could be seen. That said, in BI you can have toon shading in the 3D view ;)